# Twitter Bootstrapped installed, but how to verify if it's actually in use or not?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am on a new project at my job, and I need to update our Bootstrap from 2.x to 3.x for a new library I'm introducing. My boss says it's been installed but he doesn't think it's ever been used, and that I need to verify this. I am new to Bootstrap.

How would I go about finding out if an installed Bootstrap library is actually in use? What would I look for?

Comment: Do you want to find out if the Bootstrap library is in use in your new project or another project?

Comment: add `<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-1">Test</div></div></div>` to the page and see if it looks like a single column showed up on the page. (This would compare to bs 2.x which uses `span1` over `col-*-1`)

Comment: It is an existing project, a huge website that I cannot break. They downloaded/installed bootstrap 2, but don't believe they ever got around to actually using it. I'm trying to figure out how to tell if it is in use anywhere, such as if it is being loaded into a view (code igniter based project). Basically, I am going to start using it, but I can't risk breaking anything on an upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap defines many CSS styles at the element level. Take this example for Bootstrap 3.x:

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

If Bootstrap is included in your web app, then it is probably in use as a result of those element-level styles. I am not sure what type of web app you have, but I would look in the HTML header for a `bootstrap.css` or `bootstrap.js` file to see if Bootstrap is included. Here's an example of an import statement that you'd find in the header:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="/bootstrap.js"></script>

        ...
    </head>

    ...

</html>
```

If your web app compiles all of your CSS/JavaScript into a single file, I would try searching that one file for the Bootstrap copyright/license information:

```
* Bootstrap v3.3.5 (http://getbootstrap.com)
* Copyright 2011-2015 Twitter, Inc.
* Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
```

EDIT:

Schmalzy pointed out that the `bootstrap.js` file can be included in the `body` of the HTML file. This is entirely possible, and here is an example of that import statement:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        ...
    </head>

    <body>
        ...

        <script src="/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! We are using CodeIgniter, so I am trying to check if it has been loaded into any of the views (if I can figure out the right terminology this group would have used). See my comment on my question. If you have any other advice let me know - I will wait a few minutes before accepting this answer

Comment: Warning: the Bootstrap js file may be included somewhere other then the `<head>` of the document. Generally these are included at the bottom of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: @FaithInMotion I haven't worked with CodeIgniter before, but the demo apps that I viewed included Bootstrap in the ways that I've mentioned in my post. I would do it if I had time, but if your site is huge, maybe you can create a simple website crawler that visits each page on your site and checks for a mention of the word, `bootstrap`. It's not perfect by any means but would probably work for your purposes.